# IntelliSense: Why can't I look up DOM/CSS types?

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Trying to write my first TypeScript project, the compiler was very picky:

```
let test = <div style={{textAlign:'right'}}>Text</div>; // OK

let right = 'right';
let test2 = <div style={{textAlign:right}}>Text</div>; /***ERROR***
   Type '{ style: { textAlign: string; }; }' is not assignable to 
   type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
    Type '{ style: { textAlign: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 
    'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
     Types of property 'style' are incompatible.
      Type '{ textAlign: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
       Types of property 'textAlign' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextAlignProperty'.
*/
```

However I could not look up types such as `TextAlignProperty` with Ctrl+Shift+O (in VSCode). Is there a way to make this work?

P.S. Eventually I figured out that the types are defined in **node_modules\csstype\index.d.ts** and that I could write

```
import * as CSS from 'csstype';
...
let right = 'right';
let test = <div style={{textAlign:right as CSS.TextAlignProperty}}>Text</div>;
```

But there is an easier way:

```
let right = 'right';
let test = <div style={{textAlign:right} as any}>Text</div>;
```

So the real question here is, how do you look something up **without** knowing the name of the module that defines it?

Comment: @Ryan This is JSX code (invented for the popular React framework) which is supported by TypeScript when your file has a .tsx extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, run `Go to definition` on `textAlign` in  `<div style={{textAlign:'right'}}>Text</div>;`. This will open the d.ts file showing the expected type which you can then drill into further:

[image]

[image]

Or use [workspace symbol search](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name) to jump to the type by name directly:

[image]

Comment: I see, you have to search for `#TextAlignProperty` instead of `@TextAlignProperty`. Thanks!